# Difference between DescribeJobExecutionCommand in AWS SDK Iot and Iot-Jobs-Data-Plane?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am working with AWS SDK for Javascirpt and notice that both `iot` and `iot-jobs-data-plane` services has a command called "DescribeJobExecution" that return the current status of a job execution. However with the same set of required input like this:

```
{
 // DescribeJobExecutionRequest
  jobId: "STRING_VALUE", // required
  thingName: "STRING_VALUE", // required
}
```

The command from `iot` service manage to get the details of the job execution and return it while the one from `iot-jobs-data-plane` throw a 404 ResourceNotFoundException to me.
My business logic requires me to retrieve the jobDocument from the command so I definetely need the `iot-jobs-data-plane` one.

[iot services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/iot/command/DescribeJobExecutionCommand/)

[iot-jobs-data-plane services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/iot-jobs-data-plane/command/DescribeJobExecutionCommand/)

I have been digging around but no one seems to have my problem and I couldn't find any info from the docs either so any help would really be appreaciated.
I'm new to Stackoverflow questions so if there's anything unclear, feels free to comment so that I can edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

For anyone that struggle like me, the `iot-jobs-data-plane` needs a different endpoint compare to the `iot` one. So you need to use the command `describe-endpoint` with the `--endpoint-type` parameter set to `iot:Jobs` to find out the correct endpoint. Then pass it to the constructor of the `iot-jobs-data-plane` as a custom endpoint. After that, you can now use call the `iot-jobs-data-plane`.